how to change select all into unselect all in ngmultiselect angular
I tried like this, but it's not working properly:
 (<HTMLInputElement>(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("Categorydropdown")).children[0].children[1].children[0].children[0].children[0]).checked=true;       
      (<HTMLInputElement>(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("Categorydropdown")).children[0].children[1].children[0].children[0].children[1]).innerHTML="UnSelect All"; 

i want selectall checkbox should be selected and changing into unselectAll after calling api

Handle the select/unselect logic and update the button text.
HTML
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
  #dropdown
  [data]="dropdownList"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
  [settings]="dropdownSettings">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>

<button (click)="handleApiCall()">Call API</button>

TS
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownComponent } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown: NgMultiSelectDropDownComponent;

  selectAll() {
    this.dropdown.selectAll();
    this.updateButtonText('Unselect All');
  }

  unselectAll() {
    this.dropdown.unselectAll();
    this.updateButtonText('Select All');
  }

  updateButtonText(text: string) {
    const selectAllButton = document.querySelector('.dropdown-select-all-button'); // Modify this selector according to your button's class or id
    if (selectAllButton) {
      selectAllButton.textContent = text;
    }
  }

  handleApiCall() {
    // Your API call logic
    this.selectAll(); // or this.unselectAll() depending on your need
  }
}

